# Multithreading efficiency in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I am trying to learn threading in C++, and just had a few questions about it (more specifically `<thread>`.

Let's say the machine this code will run on has 4 cores, should I split up an operation into 4 threads? If I were to create 8 threads instead of 4, would this run slower on a 4 core machine? What if the processor has hyperthreading, should I try and make the threads match the number of physical cores or logical cores?

Should I just not worry about the number of cores a machine has, and try to create as many threads as possible?

I apologize if these questions have been already answered; I've been looking for information about threading with `<thread>`, which was introduced in c11 so I haven't been able to find too much about it.

The program in question is going to run many independent simulations.

If anybody has any insight about `<thread>` or just multithreading in general, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Create as many threads as you need is the general rule or at least make it configurable if you really want to match the number of cores on the machine but remember that your app is not the only process running on the machine.

Comment: Also note, that because of blocking operations, the optimal number of threads might be _higher_ than the number of logical cores.

Comment: Yeah the key here is to recognize how the operating system is calculating the time for each thread to spend on the CPU. Each OS has a scheduling algorithm so keep that in mind as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Comment: Nitpicking: there is no `<threads.h>` in C++11: it's `<thread>`.

Comment: @JesusRamos so say I run 1,000 simulations, each simulation taking linear time. Would creating a thread for each simulation be overkill? Would it actually increase the speed, or would the overhead from creating new threads cause a performance decrease?

Comment: It depends, you might have to do some testing but if they're computationally intensive stick to the number of cores. If they're I/O bound or something then consider adding more to balance the fact that some threads will be sleeping waiting for operations to complete.

Comment: @StevenMorad: see Arrieta's answer. If your calculations are CPU-bound then it's useless to spawn more threads than you have cores. If they are I/O-bound then you should probably spawn one thread per task. In all cases, benchmark! Cache issues can slow you down a lot too ("false sharing"), there is no definitive answer to your question.

Comment: As is, this question is probably way too general to get a good answer.  There are too many unknowns about the type of processing, the plan for dividing the work, the processor architecture, the OS and scheduler, etc., to give a specific recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

If you are performing pure calculations with no I/O - and those calculations are freestanding and not relying on results from other calculations happening in another thread, the maximum number of such threads should be the number of cores (possibly one or two less if the system is also loaded with other tasks).

If you are doing network I/O or similar, more threads are certainly a possibility.

If you are doing disk-I/O, a single thread reading from the disk is often best, because disk reads from multiple threads leads to moving the read/write head around on the disk, which just makes things slower.

If you're using threads for to make the code simpler, then the number of threads will probably depend on what you are doing.

It also depends on how "freestanding" each thread is. If they need to share data in complex ways, the sharing/waiting for other thread/etc, may well make it slower with more threads.

And as others have said, try to make your framework for this flexible and test different options. Preferably on multiple machines (unless you only have one kind of machine that you will ever run your code on).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `<threads.h>`, you mean `<thread>`, the thread support library introduced in C++11.

The only answer to your question is "test and see". You can make your code flexible enough, so that it can be run by passing an `N` parameter (where `N` is the desired number of threads).

If you are CPU-bound, the answer will be very different from the case when you are IO bound.

So, test and see! For your reference, [this link can be helpful](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). And if you are serious, then go ahead and [get this book](http://www.manning.com/williams/). Multithreading, concurrency, and the like are hairy topics.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of the number of threads you need as in comparison to the machine you're running on.  Threading is valuablue any time you have a process that:

A: There is some very slow operation, that the rest of the process need not wait for.

B: Certain functions can run faster than one another and don't need to be executed inline.

C: There is a lot of non-order dependant I/O going on(web servers).

These are just a few of the obvious examples when launching a thread makes sense.  The number of threads you launch is therefore more dependant on the number of these scenarios that pop up in your code, than the architecture you expect to run on.  In fact unless you're running a process that really really needs to be optimized, it is likely that you can only eek out a few percentage points of additional performance by benchmarking for your architecture in comparison to the number of threads that you launch, and in modern computers this number shouldn't vary much at all.

Let's take the I/O example, as it is the scenario that will see the most benefit.  Let's assume that some program needs to interract with 200 users over the network.  Network I/O is very very slow.  Thousands of times slower than the CPU.  If we were to handle each user in turn we would waste thousands of processor cycles just waiting for data to come from the first user.  Could we not have been processing information from more than one user at a time?  In this case since we have roughly 200 users, and the data that we're waiting for we know to be 1000s of times slower than what we can handle(assuming we have a minimal amount of processing to do on this data), we should launch as many threads as the operating system allows.  A web server that takes advantage of threading can serve hundreds of more people per second than one that does not.

Now, let's consider a less I/O intensive example, where say we have several functions that execute in turn, but are independant of one another and some of them might run faster, say because there is disk I/O in one, and no disk I/O in another.  In this case, our I/O is still fairly fast, but we will certainly waste processing time waiting for the disk to catch up.  As such we can launch a few threads, just to take advantage of our processing power, and minimize wasted cycles.  However, if we launch as many threads as the operating system allows we are likely to cuase memory management issues for branch predictors, etc... and launching too many threads in this case is actually sub optimal and can slow the program down.  Note that in this, I never mentioned how many cores the machine has!  NOt that optimizing for different architectures isn't valuable, but if you optimize for one architecture you are likely very close to optimal for most.  Assuming, again, that you're dealing with all reasonably modern processors.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say the machine this code will run on has 4 cores, should I split up an operation into 4 threads?

If some portions of your code can be run in parallel, then yes it can be made to go faster, but this is very tricky to do since loading threads and switching data between them takes a ton of time.

> If I were to create 8 threads instead of 4, would this run slower on a 4 core machine?

It depends on the context switching it has to do. Sometimes the execution will switch between threads very often and sometimes it will not but this is very difficult to control. It will not in any case run faster than 4 threads doing the same work.

> What if the processor has hyperthreading, should I try and make the threads match the number of physical cores or logical cores?

Hyperthreading works nearly the same as having more cores. When you will notice the differences between a real core and an execution core, you will have enough knowledge to work around the caveats.

> Should I just not worry about the number of cores a machine has, and try to create as many threads as possible?

NO, threads are hard to manage, avoid them as much as you can.

> The program in question is going to run many independent simulations.

You should look into [openmp](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/exercise.html). It is a library in C made to parallelize computation when your program can be split up. Do not confuse parallel with concurrent. Concurrent is simply multiple threads working together while parallel is made specifically to speed up your application. Maybe openmp is overkill for your thing, but it is a good thing to know when you are approaching parallel computing

Answer (score 1):

I think most people would say that large scale threading projects are better supported by languages other than c++ (go, scala,cuda). Task parallelism as opposed to data parallelism works better in c++. I would say that you should create as many threads as you have tasks to dole out but if data parallelism is more related to your problem consider maybe using cuda and linking to the rest of your project at a later time
NOTE: if you look at some sort of system monitor you will notice that there are likely far more than 8 threads running, I looked at my computer and it had hundreds of threads running at once so don't worry too much about the overhead. The main reason I choose to mention the other languages is that managing many threads in c++ or c tends to be very difficult and error prone, I did not mention it because the c++ program will run slower(which unless you use cuda it probably won't)

Comment: This is definitely something I was thinking about. I just wanted to explore a simple way of parallelism before jumping into using CUDA, etc.

Comment: Nothing about c++ is simple, I like the language but threads in some newer languages are much lighter weight and therefore you can create 1000's of them with little overhead

Comment: 'it had hundreds of threads running at once' - you mean it had hundreds of threads in existence at once, ie. hardly any ready/running.

Comment: @MartinJames, well my computer has 392 cuda cores so I'm actually most likely correct

Answer (score 0):

In regards to hyper-threading let me comment on what I have found from experience.

In large dense matrix multiplication hyper-threading actually gives worse performance.  For example Eigen and MKL both use OpenMP (at least the way I have used them) and get better results on my system which has four cores and hyper-threading using only four threads instead of eight.  Also, in my own GEMM code which gets better performance than Eigen I also get better results using four threads instead of eight.

However, in my Mandelbrot drawing code I get a big performance increase using hyper-threading with OpenMP (eight threads instead of four).  The general trend (so far) seems to be that if the code works well using `schedule(static)` in OpenMP then hyper-threading does not help and may even be worse.  If the code works better using `schedule(dynamic)` then hyper-threading may help.

In other words, my observation so far is that if the run time of each thread can vary a lot hyper-threading can help.  If the run time of each thread is constant then it may even make performance worse.  But YOU have to test and see for each case.